# Can't get colorscheme to work in vim

Tags: vim

I'm trying to get the [desert](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=105) color scheme to work in vim. So far I have my colors folder

```
~/.vim/colors/desert.vim
```

And in my .vimrc file I have the line

```
colorscheme desert
```

Syntax highlighting turns on, but without the correct colors. I'm accessing vim through iTerm on macosx. I've tried setting this up on both my local machine as well as a remote ubuntu box. On the local machine vim is at version 7.2.108 and on the remote machine vim is at version 7.1.138.

I'm just starting out with cli so let me know what I'm leaving out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using vim through a terminal and not using a graphical version like gvim or macvim, there's a chance you are in 256-color mode. I don't think the regular desert scheme is compatible with that. There's another colorscheme [desert256](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1243) you might try instead.

`colorscheme desert256`

You might also need to put something like:

`set t_Co=256`

in your .vimrc.

Comment: That in combination with Joni's suggestion worked on my local machine, but on the remote machine everything is now only a combination of two colors. A white and a sort of pinkish. Any idea where I went wrong? I've tired going back and removing colorscheme and t_Co in .vimrc as well as Term=xterm-256color in .bashrc

Comment: Turns out the pinkish color was coming from my iTerm sesssion changing the color of bolded text. I've turned that off, now I have no colors besides black background and white text.

Comment: Try to add `syntax on` to your .vimrc

Comment: Ya syntax on was already in there. The problem was the export Term command in bashrc was sticking around even after removing and sourcing the file. I found a suggestion to change the command to export TERM=xterm, leaving off the color part. That fixed it all up.